# how to create image slider in javascript

Tags: jquery

Make an Image Slider that has a button valued "Start". When it is clicked. Its value changes to "Stop". If clicked again, it becomes "Start".

And the Image Slider also starts and stops on clicking on the button.

Add "Previous" and "Next" buttons to previous and next images wether slider is moving or not.

Add mouseover and mouseout effect. When mouseover on slider it stops and mouseout of slider it continues from same place. (it should work only when slider is moving).

Comment: this is not a website where people work for you. Please show at least some effort and an attempt at solving, and everybody will be happy to help.

Comment: sory i will definately show my effort and i m trying to do it :) i had done a little bit but how to attache images i dont knw :(

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: everything you want to do about slider is here

http://tympanus.net/codrops/tag/slider/